# Body overflows if not container overflows on mobile view(375px) when i try to adjust some margins to my ul,li items,tried displaying flex but no luck

Tags: html, css, flexbox, block

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="card">
  <div class="text-stats">
    <h1>Get <span class="intext">insights</span> that help your business grow.</h1>
    <p>Discover the benefits of data analytics and make better decisions regarding revenue, customer 
    experience, and overall efficiency.</p>
    <ul class="stats">
    <li>10k+ <span class="heading">companies</span></li>
    <li>314  <span class="heading">templates</span></li>
    <li>12M+  <span class="heading">queries</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <div class="images">
      <img class="img-mobile" src="./images/image-header-mobile.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="img-desktop" src="./images/image-header-desktop.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
```

Simple 2 split centered web-page.half of it image half of it full of text.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;700&family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --clr-main-bg: hsl(233, 47%, 7%);
  --clr-card-bg: hsl(244, 38%, 16%);
  --clr-accent: hsl(277, 64%, 61%);

  --clr-heading: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  --clr-text-paragh: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  --clr-stathead: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.6);

  --ff-primary: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  --ff-secondary: "Inter", sans-serif;
}

.img-desktop {
  display: none;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: var(--clr-main-bg);
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  color: var(--clr-heading);
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  max-width: 16ch;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1;
}

p {
  color: var(--clr-text-paragh);
  font-size: 0.85em;
  max-width: 29ch;
  margin: 2em auto;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.intext {
  color: var(--clr-accent);
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container {
  padding: 2em 1em;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: var(--clr-card-bg);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.text-stats {
  order: 2;
}

.images {
  order: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.images::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: var(--clr-accent);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: var(--clr-heading);
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.heading {
  color: var(--clr-stathead);
  font-family: var(--ff-secondary);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  display:block;
}
```

I've tried almost anything i can think of and got stuck,displaying block,flexbox removed all the margins and padding and added only to my list items and no still, couldn't find the reason why my body overflows and casues vertical scrolling problem.After that i will move on desktop style with media queries.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Especially the section titled "Write a question that summarizes the problem", because the current title reads like you started writing your question in the title and only moved to the body because you ran out of room ;).